# log4j2-to-slf4j-2.10 causes 'Unable to locate a logging implementation, using SimpleLogger'

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j, log4j2

I am using spring boot 1.5.9.  I want to route from log4j2 to slf4j to logback. I have included the following dependency within maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Code to get the logger and log using log4j2:

```
public static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(TestLogging.class);
logger.error("LOG4j2================================");
logger.fatal("LOG4j2================================");
```

This produces the following error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
ERROR TestLogging LOG4j2================================
FATAL TestLogging LOG4j2================================
```

How can I route the log4j2 log statements to logback via slf4j?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you just need log4j2 as the logging interface, and you want to use logback as the logging implemention, so need to add the logback jars.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```